# Are there any tools that convert a table from MS Word to LaTeX tabular format?

Tags: tables, msword

I have a really big table in MS Word and would like to convert it to tabular format automatically. I'm using Texmaker and their quick tabular wizard is good but it doesn't let you copy paste data across column and rows from MS Word.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're using MS Word, then you must have access to MS Excel. And since movement between the two is fairly basic (copy-and-paste), I suggest using [`excel2latex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/excel2latex) to easily transfer Microsoft-related tables to LaTeX.

Comment: excel2latex appears to not work for macs. Is there a mac-friendly alternative?

Comment: I found that you can just copy-paste spreadsheet cells in TeXShop v 2.47 under "Macros ->  Paste Spreadsheet Cells". Source: http://heplife.blogspot.com/2012/05/excel-to-latex.html

Answer (score 17):

This is the best tool so far. You do not need to download anything. Totally online.

http://www.tablesgenerator.com/#

Answer (score 3):

For simple tables, I used online tool http://ericwood.org/excel2latex/

I dragged my excel ( if it is in word, as @Werner said, copy it to excel sheets) to that website and it outputs the latex code.

Comment: But your answer is to download the add in for excel which did not work for me on mac, so I searched for online tool.